# What is this gas connection fitting, and what is its purpose?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, natural-gas

I have a convenient gas line which runs to the back of the house. I would like to use this line to relocate my existing water heater.

My question is, what is this fitting on this line (a reducer)?
Do I need to open up the line more if it is to be used for a water-heater?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an offset nipple (or swivel). Quality installations keep everything parallel and square. Angled pipe is frowned upon as it suggests strain on fittings and sloppy work in general.